# Minimum Steps to One

Tags: java, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

Problem statement :

On a positive integer, you can perform any one of the following 3 steps.

1. Subtract 1 from it. ( n = n - 1 )
2. If its divisible by 2, divide by 2. ( if n % 2 == 0 , then n = n / 2  )
3. If its divisible by 3, divide by 3. ( if n % 3 == 0 , then n = n / 3  ).

Now the question is, given a positive integer n, find the minimum number of steps that takes n to 1

eg:

1. For n = 1 , output: 0
2. For n = 4 , output: 2  ( 4  /2 = 2  /2 = 1 )
3. For n = 7 , output: 3  (  7  -1 = 6   /3 = 2   /2 = 1 )

I know the solution using dynamic programming and having a integer array. here is the code.

```
    public int bottomup(int n) {
            //here i am defining an integer array
            //Exception is thrown here, if the n values is high.
            public int[] bu = new int[n+1];
            bu[0] = 0;
            bu[1] = 0;
            for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) {
                    int r = 1+bu[i-1];
                    if(i%2 == 0) r = Math.min(r,1+bu[i/2]);
                    if(i%3 == 0) r = Math.min(r,1+bu[i/3]);
                    bu[i] = r;
            }
            return bu[n];
    }
```

But i want to solve this using less space.This solution throws OutofMemoryError in java if n=100000000.I don't want to increase my heap space.Does anyone has solution using less space?

Please note this problem cannot be solved using greedy algorthm.Using one while loop and check for divisible by 3 and divisible by 2 wont work.you have to use dynamic programming.please suggest if any has a solution using less space.

eg:

For n = 10 greedy algo is 10 /2 = 5  -1 = 4  /2 = 2  /2 = 1 which takes 4 steps.where as the solution should be 10-1 = 9 / 3 = 3 / 3 = 1, 3 steps.

I even tried topdown solution.

```
    public int[] td = null;
    public int topdown(int n) {
            if(n <= 1) return 0;
            int r = 1+topdown(n-1);
            if(td[n] == 0) {
                    if(n%2 == 0) r = Math.min(r,1+topdown(n/2));
                    if(n%3 == 0) r = Math.min(r,1+topdown(n/3));
                    td[n] = r;
            }
            return td[n];
    }
```

it is failing at n=10000.

Comment: One way to do so, because the number of steps is O(log(n)), you could use short instead of int for int inputs.

Comment: On the same idea as @elyashiv, byte is enough too.

Comment: How high of an `n` do you want to be able to handle? The space considerations are *probably* why exercises like [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MST1/) limit it to `(0 < n ≤ 2*10^7 )`.

Comment: `char` is better than `short`, since the answer can never be negative. `char`s are unsigned, `short`s are signed.

Comment: I thought short could be signed.

Comment: About your top down solution: It will get a stack overflow because your recursion depth is n (because of that first 1+topdown(n-1) recursive call). My answer shows a top down solution which stops that super-deep recursion after two steps, so the total depth of recursion will be O(log n).

Answer (score 5):

One idea is that at any iteration you need the values only for `r/3` to `r`. So you can keep discarding `1/3rd` of the array.

I'm not familiar with `Java`, but with `C++` you can use a `double ended queue (deque)`:

You keep adding to the deque from the back.
When `i = 6`, you do not need `bu[0]` and `bu[1]`. So you pop out two elements from the front of the queue.

Random access `[ ]` is supported with deque container.

EDIT: Also as suggested in the comments, you should change your datatype to a smaller sized one since the maximum number of steps shall be of the order of `( (log N) to base 2)`

EDIT2: As Dukeling pointed out, it seems that in Java there is no ready-made well-suited implementation for deque that would not compromise on time complexity. You can think of implementing it in your own way as C++ does (I heard it is implemented as a vector of vectors with the size of inner vectors being small as compared to the total number of elements).

Comment: Interesting idea. What's the practical way to implement that? Some kind of queue?

Comment: [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is probably what you're looking for. Constant time random access is not natively supported for the deque ADT, as it can also be implemented as a linked-list.

Comment: Should note that in the asymptotic case the memory usage for this approach is still n/3 -> O(n)

Comment: Actually I take my previous comment back - `ArrayDeque` uses templates, which, last time I checked, unlike C++, can't use primitives, so it will use the primitive wrapper classes, which uses quite a bit of memory. You'll probably need a custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

**Recursive Solution For this problem**

```
public static int countMinStepsTo1(int n){

      if(n==1)
      {
          return 0;
      } 
      int count1,count2=Integer.MAX_VALUE,count3=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      count1 = countMinStepsTo1(n-1);

       if((n%2)==0)
       {
           count2=countMinStepsTo1(n/2);
       }
        if((n%3)==0)
        {
            count3=countMinStepsTo1(n/3);
        }

        return 1+Math.min(count1,Math.min(count2,count3));
    }
```

**DP Approch For this problem**

```
public static int countstepsDP(int n)
    {
        int storage[] = new int[n+1];
        storage[1]=0;

        for(int i=2; i<=n;i++)
        {
            int min=storage[i-1];
            if(i%3==0)
            {
                if(min>storage[i/3])
                {
                    min=storage[i/3];
                }
            }
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                if(min>storage[i/2])
                {
                    min=storage[i/2];
                }
            }
            storage[i]=1+min;
        }

        return storage[n];

    }
```

Comment: Have you tested this solution?  It seems to be ok for small `n`, but it does not produce results even for `n = 1000` and for input of n = 100_000_000 specified by OP it immediately results in StackOveflowError because it attempts to do n calls with (n-1).

Comment: it will get you the result but it will take time to do so because of the complexity of this program as it is of the order 2 to the power n.  you can try DP approach for this problem it works fine for n=100000000

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Here is updated code which I have actually tested somewhat and I believe comes to the same answers for n from 1 to 100000. I'm leaving the original answer below for reference. The flaw was the "clever" use of MAX_INT. I forgot that there would be some cases where I skipped the -1 possibility but the number would also not be divisible by 2 or 3. This solves that by returning null to mean "this path is pointless to explore further".

```
public static int steps(int n) {
    return steps(n, 0);
}
private static Integer steps(int n, int consecutiveMinusOnes) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    Integer minSteps = null;
    if (consecutiveMinusOnes < 2) {
        Integer subOne = steps(n - 1, consecutiveMinusOnes + 1);
        if (subOne != null) {
            minSteps = 1 + subOne;
        }
    }
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        Integer div2 = steps(n / 2, 0);
        if (div2 != null) {
            if (minSteps == null) {
                minSteps = div2 + 1;
            } else {
                minSteps = Math.min(minSteps, 1 + div2);
            }
        }
    }
    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        Integer div3 = steps(n / 3, 0);
        if (div3 != null) {
            if (minSteps == null) {
                minSteps = div3 + 1;
            } else {
                minSteps = Math.min(minSteps, 1 + div3);
            }
        }
    }
    return minSteps;
}
```

I believe this may work, but I haven't proved it. This algorithm is based on the idea that the only reason to subtract by one is to get you closer to a number divisible by 2 or 3. For this reason, you never really need to apply the subtract-by-one step more than two times consecutively, because if k % 3 == 2, then k - 2 % 3 == 0 and you can divide by three. Subtracting by one more times will be a wast of effort (you'll have also passed by at least one even number, so the best divide by two step opportunity will come up). This means a top down, recursive approach, and you can mix in some memoization if you want to:

```
public static int steps(n) {
    return steps(n, 0);
}
private static int steps(int n, int consecutiveMinusOnes) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    int minSteps = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (consecutiveMinusOnes < 2) {
        minSteps = 1 + steps(n - 1, consecutiveMinusOnes + 1);
    }
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        minSteps = Math.min(minSteps, 1 + steps(n / 2, 0));
    }
    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        minSteps = Math.min(minSteps, 1 + steps(n / 3, 0));
    }
    return minSteps;
}
```

DISCLAIMER: As I said above, I haven't proved this method works. I also haven't tested this particular implementation. I also haven't done the memoization stuff just because I'm lazy. Anyway, I hope that even if this doesn't quite work it gives you some ideas on how to modify your approach.

Comment: @RadhaKrishna, do you mean it gives the wrong answer? Or throws an exception? Or just hangs? I tested a Python port of this up to n=10,000 and it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Sorry n > 10000.I tried in java.it gives the following error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: I realized there's a flaw in this particular implementation. Will post an edit with a fix soon.

Comment: I've tested my updated version against the one posted in the original question, and found that it appears to work for n <= 100000.

Comment: Does it fail when `n` is 1000 times that, though? The OP has a working solution up to 100M.

Comment: I think you need to get rid of the recursion. You can't have recursion if `n` is very high. Maybe get a solution with tail recursion..

Comment: @duedl0r This approach won't work without recursion, or some equivalent (e.g. manually maintaining a stack) because it's top-down. However, the benefit over the plain recursion is that this cuts the -1 recursion short, so the total depth of recursion is going to be O(log n). And like I said, the enterprising programmer can add memoization to avoid computing stuff you've already done.

Comment: @Sean Ok, I see.. maybe you should put it on http://www.spoj.com/problems/MST1/ to prove your solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a c++ recursive Solution for the above question

// Recursive Approach

```
    int minSteps(int n)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int x, y = INT_MAX, z = INT_MAX;
        // Brute Force Approach
        x = minSteps(n - 1);
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            y = minSteps(n / 2);
        }
        if (n % 3 == 0)
        {
            z = minSteps(n / 3);
        }
        return 1 + min(x, min(y, z));
    }
```

This is the memoization technique :

// memoization
it could looks like difficult but trust me if you get to know how recursion is working memoization is the best way to improve your complexity drasticaly

```
    int memoMiniSteps(int n)
    {   
        int * arr = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0 ;i<n ;i++){
            arr[i]=-1;
        }
        if (n == 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int x, y = INT_MAX, z = INT_MAX;
        // Memoization Approach
        if(arr[n-1]!=-1){
            x = arr[n-1];
        }else{
            x = minSteps(n - 1);
            arr[n-1]=x;
        }
    
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {   
            if(arr[n/2]!=-1){
                y=arr[n/2];
            }else{
                y = minSteps(n / 2);
                arr[n/2]=y;
            }
        }
        if (n % 3 == 0)
        {
            if(arr[n/3]!=-1){
                y=arr[n/3];
            }else{
                y = minSteps(n / 3);
                arr[n/3]=y;
            }
        }
        arr[n]= 1 + min(x, min(y, z));
        return arr[n];
    }
```

// Now at last Dynamic Programming Approach It's best out of those 2 codes and simple to understand I still recommend this please try to understand the logic behind recursion first because Dp is all about optimizing the problems nothing else

DP approach

```
    int DpMinCount(int n){
        int *a = new int[n+1];
        a[0]=0;
        a[1]=0;
        for(int i =2 ; i<n+1 ;i++){
            int ans = a[i-1]+1;
            if(i%2==0){
                ans = min(ans,a[i/2]+1);
            }
            if(i%3==0){
                ans = min(ans,a[i/3]+1);
            }
        a[i]=ans;
        }
        return a[n];

}
```

Pictorial Representation :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeXOY.png)

Answer (score -2):

***This works :)***

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MinimumStepToOne {

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sscan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Give a no:" + " ");

    int n = sscan.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; n > 1; i++){

        if(n%2 == 0){n /= 2; count++;}
        else if(n%3 == 0){ n /= 3; count++;}
        else { n -= 1; count++;}

    }
    System.out.println("your no is minimized to: " + n);
    System.out.println("The min no of steps: " + count);    
 }
}
```

Comment: The result lie when the value is 10