# why return count value is not correct using reduce count algo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using minimum step reduce to one algo .I try to implement but I found one issue in javascript .It fail when I take `10` number

my function give output `4`..But expected is `3`

why 3 ?

- 10-1 =9
- 9/3 =3
- 3/3 =1

so count is `3` but my function give `4`
**references**

[Given an integer N and a set of operations, reduce N to 1 in the least amount of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498494/given-an-integer-n-and-a-set-of-operations-reduce-n-to-1-in-the-least-amount-of)

[Minimum Steps to One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547354/minimum-steps-to-one)

```
function abc(n) {
            var count = 0;

            while (true) {
                if (n === 1) {
                    break;
                }else if (n % 3 == 0) {
                    count++;
                    n = n / 3;

                } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
                    count++
                    n = n / 2

                } else {
                    count++
                    n = n - 1;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't know it should subtract one first. it is doing 10/2=5; 5-1=4;4/2=2;2/2=1

Comment: why subtract ??

Comment: The actual process for 10 is **10** / 2 → **5** - 1 → **4** / 2 → **2** / 2 → **1** according to your script. That’s four steps. `if`/`else` blocks are evaluated from top to bottom.

Comment: what is correct solution ?

Comment: answer should be `3` as per algo or `3` will be minimum steps

Comment: the correct solution seems to be to arbitrarily subtract one from n, and set count to 1, as the very first step, before the while loop - according to your expected output

Comment: your algorithm is wrong if you want the output to be 3.

Comment: oh ... in the "least amount of steps" ... you can't just go through your loop  in that sequence and hope the order of events will produce the least amount of steps

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is:

1. If N can be divided by 3: divide by 3.
2. If N can be divided by 2: divide by 2.
3. Subtract 1.

The steps you run for N = 10 are:

1. 10 can be divided by 2. Divide it by 2 => `5`.
2. 5 can't be divided by 3 or 2. Subtract 1 => `4`.
3. 4 can be divided by 2. Divide it by 2 => `2`.
4. 2 can be divided by 2. Divide it by 2 => `2`.

It takes 4 steps.

If you are interested in getting the *fastest* way to reduce N to 1, rather than just *any* way, you may be interested in the [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm.